# Replace default DataTable cell with input field

Tags: python, datatables, pyramid

How can I have input fields in my DataTable instead of it just being a cell with text? I can't seem to find any references in the docs.
This is my basic table for now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#simple-example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://127.0.0.1:6543/get_data"
    });
});
```

Comment: Your column data can be a string containing HTML, presumably an input form would work.  What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that since I've never used DataTables before. I've been looking at this example but cannot seems to get it to work thus far. http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables-1.4/example_editable.html

Comment: That's a pretty old example, if you are using the current version of Datatables, that plugin may not still work.  Can you post your source, as well as what version of the JavaScript libraries you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mRender](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender) to specify the output of each cell, so in your case you would output an HTML input control:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#simple-example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://127.0.0.1:6543/get_data",
        "aoColumns": [
                    {
                        'sWidth': '10%',
                        'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type=\'text\' value=\'' + row[0] + '\'>';
                        }

                    },
   ... more columns
                   ]
   });
})
```